# Android Toolbar esconder Search quando está aberto

Tags: android, actionbar

Eu tenho uma toolbar (actiobar) que contem um search e quando mudo de fragment, quero que esse search desapareça.
Se o search tiver fechado, basta fazer um setVisible(false) que ele esconde, no entanto, se o search tiver aberto não consigo esconder usando o setVisible(false).
Existe maneira de esconder o search quando aberto (e sem fecha-lo de forma implicita)?

Answer (score 2):

O problema que você está tendo está relacionado a definição dos menus que compoem a Action Bar em cada Fragment. Parece que você está utilizando o mesmo arquivo de menu de action bar para diferentes fragments, por isso, o item de search aparece nas outras fragments que você abre. Para resolver o problema, crie diferentes arquivos de menu para cada fragment, dessa forma, você não precisa ficar "apagando" os itens indesejados em outras fragments . Ex.:

Suponnha dois fragments  **Frag1** e **Frag2** e dois arquivos de menu, **frag_menu1.xml** e **frag_menu2.xml**;

defina os arquivos **frag_menu1.xml** e **frag_menu2.xml** e depois em cada fragment insira o método `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` no `OnCreate`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true); //define que o fragment terá um menu próprio

    // Seu código
}
```

Depois, para cada fragment, defina qual será o xml utilizado como menu através do método `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)`. No caso do **Frag2** utilizando o arquivo de menu **frag_menu2.xml**, ficará assim:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.frag_menu2,menu); //define o arquivo de menu
}
```

Depois, defina as operações para cada item do menu clicado utilizando o método `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`, que deve ser declarado no fragment correspondente, no caso do **Frag2**, o método ficaria assim:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()){

        case R.id.item_1_do_menu_frag_menu2:
            //seu código
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Se você quiser manter o estado atual do fragment ( e do menu) conforme for mudando de fragment, você deve adicionar o fragment atual na pilha de fragments antes de chamar o próximo. Isso é feito através do método `addToBackStack()`. Portanto, antes de commitar sua transação , adicione a fragment atual na pilha da seguinte forma:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                       .add(detailFragment, "detail")
                       .addToBackStack()
                       .commit();
```

Comment: Mas usando essa solucao, nao consigo manter o estado da search e da lista, ou seja, quando fizer back do Frag2, o Frag 1 nao vai ter o search view aberta com a query e a listagem filtrada

Comment: @Kiotto, modifiquei a resposta para o caso de manter o estado do fragment

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas não funciona...
Ir do FragA para o B a action bar muda como quero, mas fazendo back, a listagem já não está filtrada pela query usada antes